# error, list index out of range

Tags: python, array, lista

Me sale el error antes mencionado, ¿Dónde podría estar el error?, me recorre una matriz diciéndome los enemigos 0123456=son paises y 0=no son enemigos 1=son enemigos  , lo cual esta función me la recorre y me dice quienes son enemigos

así sería la matriz que devuelve esta función abajo adjunto la respuesta esperada

```
matriz_selecciones=[
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    [1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    [2,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [4,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [5,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
    [6,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [7,1,0,0,1,1,1,0]
                  ]
def segmentador(matriz_selecciones):
  x=0
  y=0

  SX=matriz_selecciones[0].__len__()-1
  SY=matriz_selecciones.__len__()-1
  arreglo=[SY][SX]

  for i in i<=SY:
      y=0
      arreglo[i-1][y]=matriz_selecciones[i][y]
      for j in j <=SX:
        if matriz_selecciones[i][j]==1:
          y+=1
          arreglo[i-1][y]=matriz_selecciones[0][j]
  return arreglo
  
segmentador(matriz_selecciones)

respuesta esperada, 
    

    selecciones  seleciones enemigas
     1               2 3 6 7
     2               1 5
     3                1
     4                7
     5               2 7 
     6                1 7
     7               1 4 5 6
```

Comment: si ya la identacion la corregi, 'arreglo=[SY][SX]' guardo en ese arreglo las posciones que toma SX  y SY en la matriz_selecciones

Comment: me devuelve a arreglo con los las selecciones que son enemigas

Comment: devuelve una columna con todas las selecciones y al lado pone las selecciones enemigas, busca donde halla un 1 en la fila donde esta la seleccion va hasta arriba,y escoge la seleccion y la pone en la fila al lado de la seleccion que es dueña de la fila

Comment: ya adjunte la respuesta esperada, que quiero que la funcion me retorne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo el código arreglado y con todos los cambios explicados en comentario, para cualquier otra duda pregunta:

```
matriz_selecciones = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [7, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
]


def segmentador(matriz_selecciones):
    # No se deben utilizar los "magic methods" de python, para ello están las funciones que representan
    # Tampoco hace falta usar el -1 ya que recorreremos el array ignorando la primera posición
    SX = len(matriz_selecciones[0])
    SY = len(matriz_selecciones)
    arreglo = list()  # En python no es necesario iniciar las listas con una longitud como en java

    for x in range(1, SX):  # Para cada índice en el rango 1-SX
        inner = list()  # En cada iteración creo la lista interna que añadiré luego a arreglo
        inner.append(x)  # Añado el primer valor, que es el índice
        for y in range(1, SY):  # Para cada índice en el rango 1-SY
            # print("X: ", x, "Y: ", y, "Value: ", matriz_selecciones[x][y])
            if matriz_selecciones[x][y] == 1:
                inner.append(y)  # Si el valor es 1, añado el índice y a la lista
        arreglo.append(inner)  # Al terminar el bucle interno, añado la lista

    return arreglo


result = segmentador(matriz_selecciones)

for row in result:
    print(row)
```

Resultado:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
[2, 1, 5]
[3, 1]
[4, 7]
[5, 2, 7]
[6, 1, 7]
[7, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: te lo agradezco muchas gracias

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta, por favor márcala para que sirva a otros usuarios. Además, es la mejor manera de agradecer :)